# Comparing List / CSV File Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have two lists:

```
description_list = [Cat, Cat, Bat, Horse, Bat, Cow, Pig, Pig]
time_list = [6, 8, 10, 8, 7, 1, 0, 0]
```

These lists were created from a CSV file. For example: Cat matches with the number 6 and 8, Bat matches with 10 and 7, and so on.

How do I create a new list called `cat_time` where I have a list of all of the Cat time values. For example:

```
cat_time = [6, 8]
```

Comment: `[t for d, t in zip(descriptions, times) if d == "Cat"]`

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `dict` rather than try to create separate variables:

```
from collections import defaultdict

description_list = ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Bat', 'Horse', 'Bat', 'Cow', 'Pig', 'Pig']
time_list = [6, 8, 10, 8, 7, 1, 0, 0]

times = defaultdict(list)
for time, desc in zip(time_list, description_list):
    times[desc].append(time)

print(times)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Cat': [6, 8], 'Bat': [10, 7], 'Horse': [8], 'Cow': [1], 'Pig': [0, 0]})

print(times['Cat'])
# [6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using list comprehension. For example, to find cat_time:

```
cat_list = [time_list[i] for i in range(len(description_list)) if description_list[i] == 'Cat']
```

If you want all the lists in a dictionary, could also do:

```
animals_lists = {}
for animal in set(description_list):
    animals_lists[animal] = [time_list[i] for i in range(len(description_list)) if description_list[i] == animal]
```

Which will return:

`animals_lists = {'Cat': [6, 8], 'Pig': [0, 0], 'Bat': [10, 7], 'Horse': [8], 'Cow': [1]}`